# Is there a word to describe a short forceful exhale from the nose or mouth that indicates a sarcastic or derisive laugh?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I think of the word snort the only sound that comes to mind is that nasally mucus laden inhalation noise.  Is that just my only option?

The sentence I'm trying to fit it into:
"It’s just going to take a bit more work than I’d hoped.”  Steve grinned. Sue ______.

Sue is ____ing because Steve is vastly understating the amount of work they'll need.  For more context, Sue is a mixture of playful and curious, but at this moment is having a hard time because she's starting a new job that she is woefully underprepared for.

The sound is maybe a bit like a tsk sound, or maybe a tch.  Like a very throaty tsk.  I can make the sound, but I don't know if there's a word for them. pssh?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should use the characters proper names (which might be distracting because they are a little exotic).  Just in case I generisized them.

Comment: In subtitles, I have seen this described as “scoffing” but I don’t agree with that use so not putting as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it's called snorting. snorting does not involve mucous. Pigs snort all the time. Maybe you are thinking of tongue clicking, which a while back gave way to a lengthy discussion. You can breathe in through the nose and wiggle it, that's snorting. Also, snuffling.

Comment: No, there isn't. +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Huff** is another word to describe this action. [huff](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/huff)

> Express one's feeling of petty annoyance. with direct speech ‘‘Huh!’
>   Nanny huffed’

Answer (score 37):

[*Snort*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/snort_1) is the usual word used to describe this action:

> **snort** to make a sudden loud noise through your nose, for example because you are angry or laughing

Comment: Yes, a sudden intake of air coupled with wiggling your nose from side to side. There is also snuffling. Ha ha.

Comment: [Frasier took exception to that](http://www.kacl780.net/frasier/transcripts/season_3/episode_5/kisses_sweeter_than_wine.html): **Frasier**: You just sniffed.
  **Niles**: I didn't sniff, it was a snort of contempt. [sniffs again]
**Frasier**: A snort is out, that was *in*!

Comment: Since the question is looking for a noise made by exhaling, and a snort (according to Frasier) is made by exhaling, **snort** is the right word (contrary to what the question assumes) if the sound is from the nose. If the sound is from the mouth I think a different word is required.

Answer (score 6):

**Scoff**

Scoffing is showing derision or revulsion and someone's statements.

Comment: I don't think that scoffing is related to exhaling.

Comment: It can be related - onomatopoeia is *pshaw*.

Answer (score 3):

As a verb: **Harrumph**, according to [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harrumph):

> 1. Clear the throat noisily.
>
>    1.1  Grumpily express dissatisfaction or disapproval.

As a noun: **Harrumph**, according to [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harrumph):

> 1. A noisy clearing of the throat.
>
>    1.1 A grumpy expression of dissatisfaction or disapproval.

Example sentence from the same source:

> ‘Yin Xi guessed the sound equated somewhat to a harrumph of dissatisfaction.’

Attribution:  "Harrumph | Definition of Harrumph in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed April 08, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harrumph.

Answer (score 1):

**hem** or **ahem** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ahem) aka the **throat clear**  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throat-clear)

> the utterance of a sound similar to clearing the throat; intended to
>   get attention, express hesitancy, fill a pause, hide embarrassment,
>   warn a friend, etc.