# Term (a verb) for (giving) a laugh that is a short and dry reaction when hearing something unrealistic

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb to express that short expulsion of air through the nose while you smile a bit? It isn't really a laugh, but more of a reaction. It could be something you do when you hear something you don't agree with. Like imagining a situation and then thinking

> *Yea, like that's gonna happen.*

I initially thought **scoffed**, but I'm not sure anymore by the definitions I've read.

Would it make sense to use it as follows:

> *She's a strong girl. I couldn't help but **scoff** at the thought of
>   someone hurting her.*

Comment: A bit irrelevant, but might be of interest: [Is there a word to describe a short forceful exhale from the nose or mouth that indicates a sarcastic or derisive laugh?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440537/is-there-a-word-to-describe-a-short-forceful-exhale-from-the-nose-or-mouth-that).

Comment: I might say "cackle".

Comment: **Scoff** is correct.

Comment: @HotLicks:  Interesting. In my necks of the woods, a cackle isn't a brief  thing but something that takes a second or three. It's either got more than one "syllable" or a long syllable. And it's "wet" not "short and dry".

Answer (score 3):

To scoff is to express derision, but not only by making a sound with the mouth or nose. One can scoff in many ways. Possibly you could use 'snort'.

> SNORT
> VERB
> [NO OBJECT]
> Make a sudden explosive sound through one's
> nose, especially to express indignation or derision.
>
> ‘she snorted with laughter’
>
> I was one of the people who snorted with derision when Gwyneth Paltrow
> spoke of "consciously uncoupling" with husband Chris Martin.

[Snort (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snort)

Answer (score -2):

The word you are looking for dry reaction (of smile/laugh) is ***Sardonic***. When you're being sardonic, or if you have a sardonic laugh or smile, you're making fun of someone or something in a mean, bitter way.  The sardonic is define by Meriam Webster as:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sardonic)

> showing that you disapprove of or do not like someone or something : showing disrespect or scorn for someone or something

Or
[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sardonic)

> Grimly mocking or cynical.

Usage: "If she went down in trousers he would give one of those sardonic laugh."

There are nearly 17,000 other citation of *sardonic laugh* from [Google books](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22Sardonic+laugh%22&=).

And, there are nearly 223,000 other citation of *sardonic smile* from [Google books](https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1280&bih=603&tbm=bks&ei=nMKLW4GcJ4SuvwT_sabgDg&q=sardonic+smile&oq=sardonic+smile&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2069.2069.0.2382.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.rwLhdTDjIxw)

Comment: I'd use this, Ubi, but it doesn't fulfil OP's request for a verb. I think the downvotes are harsh, though, as the title question doesn't insist on a verb. I'll add a countering UV here, then edit the question for consistency.